# pass variable from options page to content script chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

Lets say that I have
    
in options.html and I want to take the user-defined value of this and define at as a variable called keyword:
    var keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value
in my options.js. I then want to pass on the variable keyword to contentscript.js. I've looked at both Google Chrome's message passing guide and their storage guide on the dev site. I still can't execute it the way I intend to though. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: And your question is? Show us your attempts.

Comment: In fact, you created two questions today, both of which are not very good. Please read those two guides: [Site Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your questions to improve them.